# Spring Security, SSO реализация

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Нужно реализовать SSO желательно через OAuth 2, может кто-то кинуть толковых статей/примеров, то, что нашёл, почти без комментариев.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/cas.html http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-sso.html

Comment: к сожалению, тут нет готового примера, чтобы просто собрать проект и запустить, дабы понять то, что это надо или нет

Comment: Его и не будет, если вы не укажите с чем именно вы интегрируетесь. Вам нужен некий провайдер, который будет отвечать за валидацию юзер, а Spring Security всего лишь пользователь этого провайдера.

Comment: Могли бы, пожалуйста, подсказать, в какую сторону мне двигаться чтобы реализовать это? Те мне нужен уже готовый (кем-то написанный провайдер), а SS будет с ним соединяться? Я очень плохо ориентируюсь в этой теме

Comment: CAS - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Authentication_Service интеграция со спрингом первая ссылка в моём первом сообщении.

Comment: CAS это аналог OpenID, я правильно понимаю? И если так, то мне нужно найти готовый провайдер? Если не составит сложности, не могли бы поэтапно написать, что нужно сделать для реализации. Огромное вам спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36410/discussion-between-germansevostyanov-and-vartlok).

Comment: Можете оформить свой комментарий в виде ответа, и я отмечу его, как правильный.

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант вы можете использовать CAS (как уже указали) или же Gluu.

CAS не даёт возможность управления пользователями, для этого вам необходимо использовать дополнительный веб-сервис для управления пользовательской базой данных.

SSO вы можете реализовать например с помощью Spring. В качестве механизма аутентификации используйте OpenID Connect Basic (расширение OAuth 2.0 для аутентификации, больше узнать можно [здесь](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html)). Он несложно реализуется с помощью [Spring Security OAuth](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/). На стороне сервера SSO используйте настройки сервиса авторизации, на стороне клиента переопределите цепочку фильтрации Spring Security (например, [так](https://github.com/pwheel/spring-security-oauth2-client)). Далее просто реализуйте OpenID Connect Basic.

Отдельно отмечу, что в случае использования Authorization Code Grant потока в OAuth 2.0 вы можете не использовать ID Token, описанный в механизме. Об этом в частности упоминает Ryan Boyd в [этой](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021810.do) книге.

Более полное описание такого рода реализации вы можете найти здесь:

[Статья](https://github.com/TanVD/OAuth_QReal-Web/blob/master/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F%20-%20coursework.pdf)

[Реализация](https://github.com/TanVD/OAuth_QReal-Web)

Comment: Лучше перенести основную информацию из ссылок сюда, так как если ссылки станут недействительными, ответ будет бесполезен. Ссылки могут быть как дополнение.

Comment: Разумно, внёс дополнительную информацию.